Spring r2dbc Connection unexpectedly closed
im new to Spring reactive with r2dbc but i been facing this issue for 2 days, Im not able to fix.
What happpen was after the saving a data with a success response then it will keeps on Connection unexpectedly closed
i used mysql cloud from hostinger
application.properties
spring.r2dbc.url={value}
spring.r2dbc.username={value}
spring.r2dbc.password={value}


logging.level.root=DEBUG

DecodeContext-Result
2024-06-13T23:28:59.378+08:00 DEBUG 19632 --- [user-management-service] [actor-tcp-nio-3] i.a.r.m.m.server.MetadataDecodeContext   : Respond a metadata bundle by filled-up
2024-06-13T23:28:59.378+08:00 DEBUG 19632 --- [user-management-service] [actor-tcp-nio-3] i.a.r.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient    : Response: SyntheticMetadataMessage{completed=false, messages=[DefinitionMetadataMessage{database='information_schema', table='SESSION_VARIABLES' (origin:'SESSION_VARIABLES'), column='Variable_name' (origin:'VARIABLE_NAME'), collationId=224, size=256, type=253, definitions=4097, decimals=0}, DefinitionMetadataMessage{database='information_schema', table='SESSION_VARIABLES' (origin:'SESSION_VARIABLES'), column='Value' (origin:'VARIABLE_VALUE'), collationId=224, size=16384, type=253, definitions=4097, decimals=0}], eof=null}
2024-06-13T23:28:59.378+08:00 DEBUG 19632 --- [user-management-service] [actor-tcp-nio-3] i.a.r.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient    : Response: RowMessage(encoded)
2024-06-13T23:28:59.379+08:00 DEBUG 19632 --- [user-management-service] [actor-tcp-nio-3] i.a.r.mysql.client.MessageDuplexCodec    : Decode context change to DecodeContext-Command
2024-06-13T23:28:59.379+08:00 DEBUG 19632 --- [user-management-service] [actor-tcp-nio-3] i.a.r.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient    : Response: OkMessage{isEndOfRows=true, affectedRows=0, lastInsertId=0, serverStatuses=22, information='', systemVariables={}}
2024-06-13T23:28:59.379+08:00 DEBUG 19632 --- [user-management-service] [actor-tcp-nio-3] io.asyncer.r2dbc.mysql.InitFlow          : Initializing connection 640808893 context: SessionState{level=IsolationLevel{sql='READ COMMITTED'}, product='MariaDB Server', timeZone=null, lockWaitTimeout=PT50S, lockWaitTimeoutSupported=true}
2024-06-13T23:28:59.379+08:00 DEBUG 19632 --- [user-management-service] [actor-tcp-nio-3] i.a.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlSimpleConnection    : Batch is supported by server
2024-06-13T23:28:59.379+08:00 DEBUG 19632 --- [user-management-service] [actor-tcp-nio-3] reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool             : warmed up extra resource 9/9
2024-06-13T23:29:06.138+08:00  WARN 19632 --- [user-management-service] [actor-tcp-nio-2] i.a.r.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient    : Connection unexpectedly closed
2024-06-13T23:29:06.138+08:00 ERROR 19632 --- [user-management-service] [actor-tcp-nio-2] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

io.asyncer.r2dbc.mysql.client.MySqlConnectionClosedException: Connection unexpectedly closed
    at io.asyncer.r2dbc.mysql.client.ClientExceptions.unexpectedClosed(ClientExceptions.java:32) ~[r2dbc-mysql-1.1.3.jar:1.1.3]
    at io.asyncer.r2dbc.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient.handleClose(ReactorNettyClient.java:320) ~[r2dbc-mysql-1.1.3.jar:1.1.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:265) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2231) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyUnicast.checkTerminated(SinkManyUnicast.java:390) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyUnicast.drainRegular(SinkManyUnicast.java:276) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyUnicast.drain(SinkManyUnicast.java:365) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyUnicast.tryEmitComplete(SinkManyUnicast.java:205) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitComplete(SinkManySerialized.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitComplete(InternalManySink.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at io.asyncer.r2dbc.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient.resumeError(ReactorNettyClient.java:291) ~[r2dbc-mysql-1.1.3.jar:1.1.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:480) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.19.jar:1.1.19]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:275) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.19.jar:1.1.19]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundError(FluxReceive.java:468) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.19.jar:1.1.19]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundError(ChannelOperations.java:515) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.19.jar:1.1.19]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.exceptionCaught(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:145) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.19.jar:1.1.19]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:317) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.exceptionCaught(SslHandler.java:1204) ~[netty-handler-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:317) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.exceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:906) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:177) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994) ~[netty-common-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

2024-06-13T23:29:06.138+08:00 ERROR 19632 --- [user-management-service] [actor-tcp-nio-2] i.a.r.mysql.client.ReactorNettyClient    : Error: Connection reset

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:401) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:434) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:255) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:356) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994) ~[netty-common-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.110.Final.jar:4.1.110.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]


pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>wallet-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.asyncer</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>test</finalName>
    </build>

</project>



